MerchantOrderClient - 401 - invalid_caller_id Mercado Pago
I am trying to retrieve the merchant order client from the payment (which is valid), but the response from the merchant order client indicates invalid_caller_id.
PaymentClient client = new PaymentClient();
Payment payment = client.get(id);
merchant = order.get(payment.getOrder().getId());


Error 401 indicates you may not be have the right authentication or permission.

401 happens in Spring Secutiy fitler chain, meaning before it arrives to your  controller code. What you should be showing us is your SecurityConfig as well as the request you have sent
